# PPTP without default gateway

Tags: linux, pptpd

I have a Linux NAS file server with PPTP.

I have several clients that use Windows only (no Linux, MacOS or mobile phones).

I want all those clients to be able to connect to the NAS server only (no external resources), without installing any additional software on the client side. Also I want setup to be as smooth as possible, e.g. accepting defaults only.

Currently everything works with defaults, except because of default gateway, clients can not access anything but the file server.

Is there any option I can set up on the server to fix this.

Comment: You know PPTP is a horribly insecure technology, right? All the major OS vendors have already deprecated it or are in the process of doing so. At this point, it's irresponsible to continue using it.

Comment: yes, i know. I had expected comment like this, but i want to check several options and this is one of them.

Comment: Disable checkbox `use this vpn connection as default` on Windows clients in VPN connection settings​.

Comment: but nothing on the server side?

Comment: Yes. Client will disable default rote via VPN connection.